# PSD To HTML (Recommended service?)

Tags: html, css, markup, psd

I have designed a web layout using Adobe Photoshop.

Who do you recommend to convert PSD to HTML from your experience?

There are couple services do them, for example:

- www.psd2html.com
- www.xhtmlchop.com
- www.markupbox.com

or freelance from odesk.com ?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are not appropriate for StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these services should be able to do this job just fine. Finding a contractor via oDesk will probably cost you a lot more than they will.